# Cannot connect to Kubernetes using new context

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I am using Kubernetes on Minikube.
I created a user context for a new user with role and rolebinding, using
`kubectl config set-context user1-context --cluster=minikibe --namespace=default --user=user1`
When I try to see the runnig pods, target machine refuses it. But, in minikube context I can see the pods although both are running on the same cluster.

```
>kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME             CLUSTER          AUTHINFO         NAMESPACE
          docker-desktop   docker-desktop   docker-desktop
          minikube         minikube         minikube
*         user1-context    minikibe         user1

>kubectl get pods
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

>kubectl config use-context minikube
Switched to context "minikube".

>kubectl get pods
NAME         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
myapp-test   1/1     Running   0          44m
```

Config for rolebinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-pods
subjects:
  - kind: User
    name: user1
    apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: pod-reader
```

Role config

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get","watch","list"]
```

I also verified the creation of roles an rolesbinding

```
>kubectl get roles
NAME         CREATED AT
pod-reader   2020-10-20T05:59:43Z

>kubectl get rolebindings
NAME        ROLE              AGE
read-pods   Role/pod-reader   65m
```

Comment: You have a typo in your command, it should be `--cluster=minikube` and you have `--cluster=minikibe`.
Can you fix it and let me know if it works?

Comment: Yes, it worked out. Just a typo error, but took out a day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue

There was a typo in a `kubectl config set-context` command.

### Solution

Use this command with `--cluster=minikibe` typo fixed.

```
kubectl config set-context user1-context --cluster=minikube --namespace=default --user=user1
```